# Is InkToolbar available in WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, figma

I had a look at the WinUI 3 Figma file and InkToolbar is present, but it doesn't seem to be available in the WindowsAppSDK NuGet package. Is that right?

If it is available for WinUI3, how can it be implemented?

Thanks

I tried implementing the control, but I wasn't able to, and I'm confused as to why it is in the FIGMA design file.

Comment: Ink controls are not available yet for WinUI3. In fact, the current roadmap does not even mention it https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/docs/roadmap.md (but they don't update it too often so by experience it's not super meaningful) see also this https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/7426 and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/what-is-supported

Answer (score 1):

Inking is not available in WinUI 3 as per version 1.4 (experimental): neither is InkToolbar, nor is InkCanvas.  You can simulate InkCanvas using a regular Canvas and drawing shapes (lines) on it, you can even trap the pen pressure to simulate the thickness.

Here is a code snippet that does it:

```
    bool penDown = false;
    Point oldPoint;

    InkStrokeBuilder inkStrokeBuilder = new InkStrokeBuilder();
    List<InkStroke> strokes = new List<InkStroke>();
    List<Point> currentStrokePoints;

    private void Canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Microsoft.UI.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse ||
            e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Microsoft.UI.Input.PointerDeviceType.Pen)
        {
            penDown = true;
            var pnt = e.GetCurrentPoint(DrawCanvas);
            oldPoint = pnt.Position;
        }

        currentStrokePoints = new List<Point>();
        currentStrokePoints.Add(oldPoint);
    }

    private void DrawCanvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!penDown) return;

        var pnt = e.GetCurrentPoint(DrawCanvas);

        Line line = new Line();
        line.X1 = oldPoint.X;
        line.Y1 = oldPoint.Y;
        line.X2 = pnt.Position.X;
        line.Y2 = pnt.Position.Y;
        line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        line.StrokeThickness = 2 * pnt.Properties.Pressure;

        DrawCanvas.Children.Add(line);

        oldPoint = pnt.Position;

        currentStrokePoints.Add(pnt.Position);
    }

    private void DrawCanvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        penDown = false;
        currentStrokePoints.Add(e.GetCurrentPoint(DrawCanvas).Position);
        strokes.Add(inkStrokeBuilder.CreateStroke(currentStrokePoints));
    }
```

You can also later use `InkAnalyzer`, which is available in WinUI 3.

P.S.  In one of the Community Calls, someone from the team mentioned that the team who is responsible for inking "might look into it", whatever that might mean.  It may also mean "forget about it".